# wampserver-Apache 2.4.9 configuration for ssl not working

Tags: apache, ssl, wampserver

I follow https://madurad.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/redirect-http-to-https-with-wamp-server/ to set up ssl in my wampserver.When I test the configuration,I got a error:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin>httpd -t
AH00526: Syntax error on line 213 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/extra/h
ttpd-ssl.conf:
Invalid command 'Override', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not includ
ed in the server configuration
```

There is my configuration in the part of line 213,this is Directory....
/Directory configuration.

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
   Override All 
   Order allow,deny 
   allow from all 
   SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `override` parameter!

What I think you mean is `AllowOverride` so try

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
   AllowOverride All                             <-- fix1
   Order allow,deny 
   allow from all 
   SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
```

Additionally Apache 2.4 changed the syntax of the `Order...` and `Allow ...` to `Require ...`

So the syntax should be

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
   AllowOverride All                             <-- fix1
   Require all granted                           <-- fix2
   SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
```